# Finding determinant with torch.det doesn't return 0?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to find the determinant of a matrix using `torch.det`. However, it seems like I'm either not doing it right or the function is not working properly (the results should be 0 rather than a small number).

```
a = torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0])
b = torch.tensor([3.0, 3.0])

c = torch.stack([a,b], dim = 1)
print(c)
torch.det(d)
>>>tensor([[1., 3.],
        [1., 3.]])
tensor(1.2517e-06)
```

Another example:

```
a = torch.tensor([2, -1, 1]).float()
b = torch.tensor([3, -4, -2]).float()
c = torch.tensor([5, -10, -8]).float()

d = torch.stack([a,b,c], dim = 1)
print(d)
print(torch.det(d))
>>>
tensor([[  2.,   3.,   5.],
        [ -1.,  -4., -10.],
        [  1.,  -2.,  -8.]])
tensor(1.2517e-06)
```

**Update 1:**
I think I had a typo in the first example (I restarted everything and reran it):

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0])
b = torch.tensor([3.0, 3.0])

c = torch.stack([a,b], dim = 1)
print(c)
torch.det(c)
>>> tensor([[1., 3.],
        [1., 3.]])
tensor(0.)
```

Though, I believe the second example should also be 0

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, I get `tensor(0.)` in both cases (with pytorch versions 1.5.0 and version 1.8.1). What version are you using ? However I believe you made mistakes when copypasting : `d` is not defined in the first snippet and your two determinants are suspiciously equal.

Comment: Very weird. I'm using 1.7.1. I updated that print statement

Comment: Please see my update